# how to install the latest version of ansible by pip OFFLINE

Tags: python, pip, ansible, yum, rhel

we are working on linux redhat 7.2

first we download the ansible pkgs on machine

```
pip download ansible
Collecting ansible
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/5d/e10b83e0e6056dbd5b4809b451a191395175a57e3175ce04e35d9c5fc2a0/ansible-2.9.9.tar.gz (14.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 14.2MB 73kB/s
  Saved ./ansible-2.9.9.tar.gz
Collecting jinja2 (from ansible)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/9e/f663a2aa66a09d838042ae1a2c5659828bb9b41ea3a6efa20a20fd92b121/Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 2.7MB/s
  Saved ./Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyYAML (from ansible)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/c2/b80047c7ac2478f9501676c988a5411ed5572f35d1beff9cae07d321512c/PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 2.0MB/s
  Saved ./PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz
Collecting cryptography (from ansible)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/fc/a92bad2460d349ee9eb868f9f9dcddb7c8f42a45677d53a5c663fa251e75/cryptography-2.9.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.7MB 371kB/s
  Saved ./cryptography-2.9.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2->ansible)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/40/f3adb7cf24a8012813c5edb20329eb22d5d8e2a0ecf73d21d6b85865da11/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
  Saved ./MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 (from cryptography->ansible)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/29/8001b940ef40e7a25ffe8f3188bc9b118934b513d64f769dbf461e46f4ed/cffi-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (387kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 389kB 1.9MB/s
  Saved ./cffi-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting six>=1.4.1 (from cryptography->ansible)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ff/48bde5c0f013094d729fe4b0316ba2a24774b3ff1c52d924a8a4cb04078a/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Saved ./six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipaddress; python_version < "3" (from cryptography->ansible)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/f8/49697181b1651d8347d24c095ce46c7346c37335ddc7d255833e7cde674d/ipaddress-1.0.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Saved ./ipaddress-1.0.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting enum34; python_version < "3" (from cryptography->ansible)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/2c/a9386903ece2ea85e9807e0e062174dc26fdce8b05f216d00491be29fad5/enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl
  Saved ./enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography->ansible)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/e7/d9c3a176ca4b02024debf82342dab36efadfc5776f9c8db077e8f6e71821/pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 3.3MB/s
  Saved ./pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Successfully downloaded ansible jinja2 PyYAML cryptography MarkupSafe cffi six ipaddress enum34 pycparser
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

now we disconnect the machine from network
and we intend to install the following files by pip

```
# ls -ltr
total 17508
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14222889 May 25 20:36 ansible-2.9.9.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   125774 May 25 20:36 Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   269377 May 25 20:36 PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2728298 May 25 20:36 cryptography-2.9.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    24348 May 25 20:36 MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   387834 May 25 20:36 cffi-1.14.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10963 May 25 20:36 six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    18159 May 25 20:36 ipaddress-1.0.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    11223 May 25 20:36 enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   112041 May 25 20:36 pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

how to install the ansible pkgs/file by pip without network ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: `pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/download/dir/ ansible-2.9.9.tar.gz`